# How to stop autoplay ads with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, flash

I have a somewhat novel request.

I run ads on my website. The ad network I use proactively blocks autoplay flash ads. However, sometimes some get through. Because of their auto-repeat nature, autoplay flash ads hog up CPU and decrease user experience. So, I'm wondering, is there some script that I can cook up in JavaScript that automatically pauses / stops flash ads? The idea is, I'd embed this script on my website and if a flash ad is shown, it would be automatically paused.

Any ideas? I'm totally stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Message your ad network and ask them why they're messing up... Seriously, it's their problem, and you shouldn't have to fix it on your end. Also what is the ad network?

Comment: I'm in contact with them. They are working on it, but I'd rather have a second layer of defense, so to speak.

Comment: This might be adopted by major browsers soon enough: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/207541-chrome-will-soon-pause-auto-playing-flash-ads-by-default Besides that, I've never worked with interacting with flash via js :)

Comment: Yeah, I know it is possible on the user side, but I'm trying to get it done on the server side.

Comment: For this, you should actually do it on the client. I can't think of a good way to check whether a flash ad is autoplayable on the server side.

Comment: That is the question isn't it. I know it is possible to pause, but I first need to know how to detect if a flash ad is playing or not.